# how to code to fail update operation preemptively in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am working on a scenario where I am updating the record of a specific table, updating is working fine but I have put IF condition whenever update gets failed. Now, I want to code to preemptively fail the update operation here. So, I can check whether the message I am showing is rendered or not.

```
public function update() {

    $this->status = 'Active';
    if (!$this->update()) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
//status is a field of a table.
```

Comment: $this what does it refer to? To ActiveRecord?

Comment: yes the model that extends ActiveRecord, by the way, my problem is solved.

Comment: replace "if (!$this->update()) {..}"  to "return parent::update();"